# Select Box Trigger Events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have JavaScript creating a generic select box when you double click in a table cell and when an option is clicked, the select box is removed and the option selected is recorded. The table cell displays the option selected.

However, if the table cell is double clicked and the select box is created, but then you just click out of the select box without selecting an option, the select box remains and the rest of the page from then on breaks.

I want the select box to be removed if the focus is lost, but the `onblur` method that works with input boxes doesn't seem to work with select boxes.

Does anyone know what event is triggered?

JavaScript code when table cell is double clicked to make a select box:

```
var object_input = document.createElement ("SELECT");   //Put an select box in the cell
    
object_input.setAttribute("name", "course_price_select");
object_input.setAttribute("id", "course_price_select");
object_input.style.width = (current_cell.clientWidth - 20) + "px";
        
object_input.attachEvent ("onblur", focus_lost);  
object_input.attachEvent ("onkeypress", checkForEnter);
```

These two lines don't work! (`focus_lost` and `checkForEnter` methods start with `alert('hi');` so I know they are not being triggered)

```
object_input.onchange = function() {focus_lost()};

//Populate with options....
```

Comment: `attachEvent` is specific to IE. Try using `addEventListener` too.

Comment: Odd, I use attachEvent in my input boxes and it works fine on all browsers.

Comment: Sorry, that simply can't be. For example > http://jsfiddle.net/sFx7u/1/ does not trigger in Chrome unless you use the sample in my answer. It triggers `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attachEvent'`. `attachEvent` is IE-only!

Comment: I've changed it to your code below, just in case. It's been working for years but I must have some other code somewhere to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attachEvent` is an IE only function. You should also bind your events using `addEventListener`, for example:

```
if(object_input.addEventListener)
{
    object_input.addEventListener('blur', focus_lost);  
    object_input.addEventListener('keypress', checkForEnter);
}
else
{
    object_input.attachEvent('onblur', focus_lost);  
    object_input.attachEvent('onkeypress', checkForEnter);
}
```

You can see a jsFiddle [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFx7u/).

You should note that `addEventListener` does not require the events to be prepended with `on`, while `attachEvent` does.

Comment: Thanks very much Ben! Worked great. (apparently I can't accept your answer for 4 minutes, so bare with me there). But thanks again for your quick response. Much appreciated.